# Prevent process from killing itself using pkill

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a stop routine for a start-up service script:

```
do_stop()
{
  rm -f $PIDFILE
  pkill -f $DAEMON || return 1
  return 0
}
```

The problem is that pkill (same with killall) also matches the process representing the script itself and it basically terminates itself. How to fix that?

Comment: use pgrep and loop then kill?

Comment: I was intending to do that, but asked the question here in case there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can explicitly filter out the current PID from the results:

```
kill $(pgrep -f $DAEMON | grep -v ^$$\$)
```

To correctly use the `-f` flag, be sure to supply the whole path to the daemon rather than just a substring. That will prevent you from killing the script (and eliminate the need for the above `grep`) and also from killing all other system processes that happen to share the daemon's name.

Comment: For me in bash `pgrep` finds also the pid of the subshell and prints an ugly warning when trying to kill it.

Answer (score 14):

`pkill -f` accepts a full blown regex. So rather than `pkill -f $DAEMON` you should use:

```
pkill -f "^"$DAEMON
```

To make sure only if process name starts with the given daemon name then only it is killed.

**A better solution** will be to save pid (Proces Id) of the process in a file when you start the process. And for the stopping the process just read the file to get the process id to be stopped/killed.

Comment: "storing the pid" approach will inevitably create more problems than it solves. Keep it simple

Comment: This still causes pkill to kill itself, any ideas? < sudo pkill -9 -f "perl.*"debconf/frontend

Comment: `pkill` should not kill itself

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your question, you're not hard over on using pgrep and pkill, so here are some other options commonly used.

1) Use `killproc` from `/etc/init.d/functions` or `/lib/lsb/init-functions` (which ever is appropriate for your distribution and version of linux).  If you're writing a service script, you may already be including this file if you used one of the other services as an example.

```
Usage: killproc [-p pidfile] [ -d delay] {program} [-signal]
```

The main advantage to using this is that it sends SIGTERM, waits to see if the process terminates and sends SIGKILL only if necessary.

2) You can also use the secret sauce of killproc, which is to find the process ids to kill using `pidof` which has a `-o` option for excluding a particular process.  The argument for `-o` could be `$$`, the current process id, or `%PPID`, which is a special variable that pidof interprets as the script calling pidof.  Finally if the daemon is a script, you'll need the -x so your trying to kill the script by it's name rather than killing bash or python.

```
for pid in $(pidof -o %PPID -x progd); do
    kill -TERM $pid
done
```

You can see an example of this in the article [Bash: How to check if your script is already running](https://blog.jay2k1.com/2011/11/30/bash-how-to-check-if-your-script-is-already-running/)